# Apply CSS formatting to every instance of font-weight:bold

Tags: html, css

This question demonstrates my fundamental lack of understanding of CSS, but I am having trouble finding out through research on the web whether this is possible.

### Goal

Make all instances of `font-weight: bold` in an HTML file look like styled code (for example, how Markdown presents text when surrounded by backticks)

### What won't work

The HTML is output by a VSTS extension that does not allow me to:

- Add IDs or classes to the HTML document
- Use JavaScript or any other method to programmatically alter the HTML or CSS

### Proposed solution that I am not sure is possible or recommended

I am hoping there is a way to modify the CSS in this manner (the purpose of this example is to communicate my objective; I understand it does not work):

```
font-weight: bold {
  color: purple
}
```

I understand this question is probably ridiculous, but thank you for any ideas or for confirmation that this is not possible.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why don't you instead modify the styles that assign `font-weight: bold` to instead do `color: purple` or whatever?

Comment: Confirmation from my side: Not possible.

Comment: I apologize for not explaining more fully. The full process is:(1) User enters text in a VSTS HTML work-item field, (2) the VSTS extension generates that text in a report, (3) the VSTS extension applies custom styles to the generated HTML report. I cannot modify the CSS VSTS applies to the original work-item field. @Roddy of the Frozen Peas

Comment: How is the bold font weight applied? If the words are just wrapped in `strong` tags, then you can apply your CSS to the `strong` tags.

Comment: Do you know how VSTS HTML get this `font-weight: bold` style?

Comment: As you can't alter anything,  can't see how you are going to apply anything either...? Instead of telling what you can't do, show the html and explain what you can do when it comes to apply style/CSS

Comment: This is my current CSS @LGSon - so far, all the CSS I have applied has successfully modified the HTML. https://github.com/HealthCatalyst/bravo-notes-template/blob/master/bravo.css

Comment: It is wrapping them in `<span style="font-weight:bold;">text</span>` @APAD1

Comment: With that markup, use the attribute selector, e.g. `div[style*="font-weight:bold"]{color: purple;}` ... this solution was also given but deleted after a downvote, so lets see if they undelete it

Comment: @LGSon It worked perfectly when I applied `[style*="font-weight:bold"]{color: purple;}`. I hope they undelete their comment because they were right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your comment :

> It is wrapping them in `<span style="font-weight:bold;">text</span>`

You can use the CSS selector `[attribute*=value]` in this way:

```
span[style*="font-weight:bold"]{
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

Now every span with style `font-weight:bold` will get the CSS.

See my example in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/shayki5/pen/yxNVXa).

Note: you can use `span[style*="bold"]` and it will work also if in the span the style is: `font-weight: bold` (with space).

Comment: Do note, you have an extra space between `:` and `bold` in your CSS rule, which OP's tag seems not to have. Clarify that in your answer, that they need to match

Comment: Thank you kindly Shayki Abramczyk!

Comment: Since this would break if there _was_ a space after the `:` I think you can shorten it to `span[style*="bold"]`